# Get a numy nd array from a Series of array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas Series of ndarray and wanna get a matrix out of it. The matrix ideally should be a np.ndarray with shape of (2,3,2). However, the code below always prints an array with shape of (2,)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mat = pd.Series([np.array([[1, 1],[2, 2],[3, 3]]), np.array([[5, 5],[6, 6],[7, 7]])])
    # 0    [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
    # 1    [[5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7]]
    # dtype: object
arr = np.array(mat.values)
print(arr.shape)  # (2,), instead of (2,3,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)

```
arr = np.stack(mat)
print(arr)

array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[5, 5],
        [6, 6],
        [7, 7]]])
```